# Don't understand where is syntax error ? PostgreSQL 11

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, syntax-error, psql

PostgreSQL version : 11.1
Platform : OSX Mojave 10.14.1

That's my SQL code:

```
COPY (select nom,prenom,num_carte,pdv_carte,email,date_naissance from compte where num_carte != '' order by id_compte) TO :export_file WITH DELIMITER AS ';' CSV FORCE QUOTE * ENCODING 'UTF-8';
```

That line is in a .sql file called by shell script like this :

```
psql --dbname=test -U postgres --set adresses=$DATA_ADRESSE --set export_file="$EXPORT_FILE" --file=$ANO_SQL 1>>$ANO_LOG
```

With EXPORT_FILE variable declared like that :

```
export EXPORT_FILE=‎⁨"'export_for_fid.csv'"
```

Tried many solutions but none worked, always the same syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "‎⁨"
LINE 1: ...where num_carte != '' order by id_compte) TO ‎⁨'export_for_fid.csv' WITH D...
                                                       ^
```

Comment: What is the output of `select version();`

Comment: Yeah, excuse me i forgot the version `PostgreSQL 11.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit`

Comment: instead of `--set export_file="$EXPORT_FILE" --file=$ANO_SQ`, you could use a `here-document` in your shell script. This will greatly  simplify your quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using --file and --set arguments, you could use a here-document in your shell script:  (NOTE: I replaced the `COPY` by a `\COPY` )

```
#!/bin/sh

EXPORT_FILE="export_for_fid.csv"
DB_NAME="test"

psql --dbname=${DB_NAME} -U postgres <<OMG
\COPY (select nom,prenom,num_carte,pdv_carte,email,date_naissance from compte where num_carte <> '' order by id_compte) TO '${EXPORT_FILE}' WITH DELIMITER AS ';' CSV FORCE QUOTE * ENCODING 'UTF-8';
OMG

#eof
```

Comment: but the path to my csv have to be relative ? or it could be an absolute path ?

Comment: Both. (try it!)  Note that the`COPY` path refers to the **server** (as user postgres) , the `\COPY` path lives on the **client** side.

Comment: Except if you specify a path where the *connected-as* user can write (such as `/tmp/myfile.csv`

Comment: Thank u very much for ur help, but i have that when i want to use a path : `‎⁨/tmp/export_for_fid.csv: No such file or directory`

Comment: Maybe it lives on the other machine? (client <--> server)

Comment: it's a local server :-/